# register custom tel/callto app in Windows 10

Tags: windows, registry, windows-10, regedit, tel

I built this script I share with you here that worked perfectly on my Windows 7 computer to dail a tel:-link in a webpage with my Yealink VOIP phone. With the 'reg-file' you see in the comment I activated the tel-link uasage of my script. But now in Windows 10 I can't get it to work any more! Can anyone help me how I can "link" the "tel link" in a browser to my script again in Windows 10?

```
/*
test usage: cscript Z:\tel_link_open\tel.js [phone number]

create register_me.reg with:
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel]
@="URL:knoop.frl Custom Telephone Protocol for VoIP phone"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open\command]
@="cscript \"Z:\\tel_link_open\\tel.js\" -c \"\\%1\"" 

*/

var call_number = WScript.Arguments(0);
call_number = call_number.replace(/\|.+/g,'');
//                                  spatie -.
call_number = call_number.replace(/(\\tel:|%20|\(|\)|[a-z:\\ -]+)/g,'');
//                                    +      31       (    0   )
call_number = call_number.replace(/(\+|%2b)([0-9]+)(\(|%28)0(\)|%29)/ig,'00$2');
call_number = call_number.replace(/^0031/ig,'0');

WScript.Echo("\n\nGoing to dail: " + call_number + "\n\n");

//WScript.Sleep(50000000);

var outgoing_uri = "31"+"513"+"[number]"+"[internal extension]";
var login_name   = "XXX";
var login_pass   = "yyy";
var get_url      = "http://192.168.xx.yy/servlet?number=" + call_number + "&outgoing_uri=" + outgoing_uri;

// Load the WinHttpRequest object.
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");

// HttpRequest SetCredentials flags
HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0;

// Specify the target resource.
WinHttpReq.open( "GET", 
                                 get_url, 
                                 false );

if (login_name.length) { // Set credentials for server.
    WinHttpReq.SetCredentials( login_name, 
                                                         login_pass,
                                                         HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
}

// It might also be necessary to supply credentials 
// to the proxy if you connect to the Internet 
// through a proxy that requires authentication.

// Send a request to the server and wait for 
// a response.
WinHttpReq.send( );

// Display the results of the request.
WScript.Echo( "Result status: " + WinHttpReq.Status + "   " + WinHttpReq.StatusText + "\n");
WScript.Echo( WinHttpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders( ) );

/* To save a binary file use this code instead of previous line
BinStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
BinStream.Type = 1;
BinStream.Open();
BinStream.Write(WinHttpReq.ResponseBody);
BinStream.SaveToFile("out.bin");
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a solution at MSDN Microsoft:

*Registering the Application Handling the Custom URI Scheme
To register an application to handle a particular URI scheme, add a new key, along with the appropriate subkeys and values, to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. The root key must match the URI scheme that is being added. For instance, to add a scheme, add an [Protocol Name] key to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, as follows:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   [Protocol Name]
      URL Protocol = ""

Under this new key, the URL Protocol string value indicates that this key declares a custom pluggable protocol handler. Without this key, the handler application will not launch. The value should be an empty string.
...
When a user clicks a link containing your custom URI scheme, Windows Internet Explorer launches the pluggable protocol handler registered for that URI scheme. If the specified open command specified in the registry contains a %1 parameter, Internet Explorer passes the URI to the registered pluggable protocol handler application.*

further details see under

[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

This is working for tel-URI, but callto-URI is somewhere registered by Skype. You have to search in registry for it and add your application there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.